# React Typescripts redux toolkit action return type errors on object chaning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am trying to create a type for my state and also use it to type a return type of my action.

types:

```
export type CardQuery = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  photos: [];
};

export type InitialState = {
  cards: CardQuery[];
  isLoading: boolean;
  error: string;
};
```

action (using redux toolkit):

```
reducers: {
    getCards: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<InitialState>) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        cards: payload.data?.product.sales,
        isLoading: payload.loading,
      };
    },
  },
```

When i use `PayloadAction` and try to type it with `<InitialState>` which has all the elements that the action would return i get this errors:

`Property 'data' does not exist on type 'InitialState'.`
`Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'InitialState'. Did you mean 'isLoading'?ts(2551)`

I am confused as to why TS would care how i chain my object, it should just care what i return..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing type of state and type of payload.
`PayloadAction<P>` means that the type of payload should be P, it does not mean state's type.

So in your code, `PayloadAction<InitialState>` means payload should be object that would be has 3 properties `cards`, `isLoading`, `error`, so current issue is obviously occurred. There was no any property named `data`, `loading` in your payload. At least it is type error, you should need to change `InitialState` with actual type of object you are sending from `dispatch`.